# Is Vengeance of Samiel really unusable by vampires of Generations 9 or higher?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

In V20 (both Masquerade and Dark Ages) Vengeance of Samiel costs 3 blood points to use. In  Masquerade all neonates may learn it. But can they use it if they can't spend 3 blood points per turn?

If they can't, [moving it to level 6 in Dark Ages](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86947/why-did-the-designers-move-vengeance-of-samiel-valeren-to-level-6-in-v20) seems even more understandable, as one only needs to buy another dot of Generation Background, and if he doesn't have it at all, he can't use the power anyway.

Are there any other such "mistakes" in V20?

Comment: Don't have the book on me, hence no full answer, but as far as I can remember you can build up the required cost over multiple turns, can't you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As detailed in the description of Tenebrous Form (Obtenebration •••••), the expenditure of blood to invoke such powers may be spent over multiple turns, with the power taking effect in the turn the final blood is spent.

There are several other powers that require the expenditure of 3 blood points but are not placed at level 6 or higher. A brief list:

- Clotho's Gift (Temporis 5)
- Inscribe the Curse (Ogham 3)
- Moon and Sun (Ogham 4)
- Permanency (Path of Conjuration 2)

Comment: Don't forget Necromany, The Corpse in the Monster. Its level 5 power Gift of Life requires the Kindred to use multiple turns to spend 12 blood points. He may even feed as long as a vessel is present.